# How to make a gtktextview drop to the next row when getting to the border of the window?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to make a textview that will output strings that may be multiple rows long, and to divide them when they reach the border of the window. The window is set to non-resizable, so its size is fixed.

I tried to get the column and row numbers and work with these, but each character has a different size in pixels, so while a row full of "m" characters would reach the end of the row with the tenth character, a row of "0" would need about sixteen characters to get to the end of the line.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what behavior you are asking for. Do you want the text view to scroll? If so, you need to put it in a GtkScrolledWindow. Or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to implement line wrapping in a GtkTextView. You don't need to do it yourself, the text view widget already supports line wrapping. To turn it on, call `gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode()` with the text view and the appropriate wrap mode, such as `GTK_WRAP_CHAR`.